# How do you Install PHP5 without installing Apache in ubuntu?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, php

Is it possible to install PHP5 without installing apache, in Ubuntu?

If so, how?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```

Should do it.

Comment: Care to explain? I understand why installing `php5-fpm` before `php5` does the trick. But what `php5-cli` has to do with it?

Comment: `php5-cli` does not have apache as a dependency.

Answer (score 18):

Install `php5` **after** `php5-fpm` if you plan to use nginx for example, because `php5` needs one of either `libapache2-mod-php5`, `libapache2-mod-php5filter`, `php5-cgi`, or `php5-fpm`.  Apt just picks the first package that satisfies the dependency.

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-fpm php5
```

Comment: That does the trick!

Comment: This really is the much better answer.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible to install PHP5 without installing apache, in Ubuntu.

> According to this answer:
>   https://serverfault.com/a/243301/232590

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli
```